# Can glsl main() have params or return a value?

Tags: glsl

I haven't ever seen anyone declare main as anything but void main() or void main(void) but I'm curious, is it possible to have a parameter or return value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, glsl can't have parameters in the `main` function (as well as return values).

The [doc](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_%28GLSL%29) says:

> Just like in C/C++, execution of a shader begins with the function main. **This function takes no parameters and returns no values.**